# How do I show noscript content in my Angular app?

Tags: html, angular, noscript

I want to display html content for users who don't use javascript in my Angular app, how can I do it?

Using the noscript tag in the index.html file doesn't work

```
<body>
    <noscript>Test</noscript>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked in my local system, the `noscript` tag works great, please try restarting the server once, it will start working.

#### [To disable Javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable)

next to refresh button on browser press the button next to url, then click on site settings and new tab will open, there disable javascript!

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable javascript!</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```